# Is 'or' considered as a tag when filtering?

Tags: support, tags, review, error-message, tag-filters

In review queues I'm trying to filter tasks like this

> [python] or [javascript] or [c++]

but I get an message saying

> A maximum of 3 tags are allowed.

Is this supposed to happen? Is 'or' also considered as a tag here? What is the reason behind this behavior?

[image]

Comment: You cannot put any sort of additional words in the tag box. Just tags. If you're not sure what tags to put then perhaps leave it alone for the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tags in the review queue tag filter are (unlike the regular site search) *always* joined through `OR`; you don't need to add it, and neither is it possible to review only tasks within the intersection of two (or more) tags. You also don't need to use square brackets; just `python javascript c++` will suffice.

Comment: The fact that it's counted as a tag is still a bug, even if it's not necessary.